# Why do I get a "Specified cast is not valid"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, wpf, sqlite

Here is my code for selecting a single row from db table and inserting text it into corresponding text field :

```
try
{
    MessageBox.Show("page=" + GlobalVars.id);
    Query = "select Id,Description from SaleItemList where Id = '" + 
        GlobalVars.id + "';";

    cmd = new SQLiteCommand(Query, GlobalVars.conn);

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    if ((dr != null) && (dr.HasRows))
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            txttitle.Text = dr.GetString(1);
        }
    }

    dr.Close();
    cmd.Dispose();
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

It results in this error:

> Specified cast is not valid`

on this line: `txttitle.Text = dr.GetString(1);` or  `txttitle.Text = dr.GetString(2);`

My database table is :

```
CREATE TABLE "SaleItemList"
(
   "Id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE ,
   "Description" VARCHAR NOT NULL  UNIQUE
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use SQL Parameters firstly. DONT use in line values for SQL statements - its a huge security risk.

Comment: How do you open/close your connection? One possible cause is that you don't manage properly the `SQLiteConnection` object.

Comment: yes the actual problem was in open/close connection.Thanks for acknowledgement.